How to connect PC to Fa0/6 and ping router?
The following is the question I have been given.
I have set everything up on the routers and switches as has been asked. What I am struggling with is connecting the PC; the last item in the question:


Connect PC0 to Fa0/6 and give it an IP address within Newton’s Subnet 0, Ping from PC0 to 99.0.0.1 [Newton].)


Every time I ping the router (Newton) it gives me 0/5 and says not connected. I'm not sure what to do here as in packet tracer, the IP config window was super easy to navigate and modify if something went wrong.

4.1 Task 1: Router on a stick

You will need to adapt the configuration on both Newton and Einstein and configure the Heisenberg and Schrodinger switches to complete this task.
You will need to VLSM the network.
VLSM for 4 further subnets on Newton and 32 on Einstein.
On Newton:

Create two sub interfaces, for VLANs 10 and 20. - Enable dot1q trunking for each sub interface.

Using VLSM, split 172.16.0.0/24 into further subnets. VLAN 10 will be in Subnet 0, VLAN 20 will be in Subnet 1. Create suitable interface IP addresses and subnet masks to reflect this configuration requirement.
On Heisenberg:

Create VLANS 10 and 20, associate interfaces 6 thru 12 with VLAN 10 and associate interfaces 13 thru 18 with VLAN 20. (1 mark)

Enable dot1q trunking for VLAN’s 10 and 20 via Fa0/5. (1 mark) Working on PC0 as per figures 2 and 4:

Connect PC0 to Fa0/6 and give it an IP address within Newton’s Subnet 0, Ping from PC0 to 99.0.0.1 [Newton].)
^ This is the part I'm struggling with.



